# XHTML 1.0 strict the attribute data-bind is not permitted for hte <ul> tag

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, master-page, suitebar

Can anyone help me with error please. I have added knockout in at the beginning of the code with: 

I am using sharepoint designer 2013, and am very new to this - so I am sure there is an easy answer that I am missing.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data attributes are not a part of the XHTML specification hence the error that you are seeing. If you don't need to comply with the XHTML specification you can simply ignore the error. Otherwise you would have to use HTML5 instead.